# Reverse a singly linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a linked list and return the new head.

```
public Node reverse(Node head) {
    Node node = head;
    if (node.next == null) {
        head = node;
        return head;
    }
    Node next = node.next;
    reverse(next);
    next.next = node;

    return head;
}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
}
```

With input 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 I get output 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1. Why does it cycle through the first 2 nodes and leave out the remaining 3? Also, why has the new head not updated to node 5?

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I think if you pushed your list on a stack and then created a new list from the head of the stack (or cleared the old list) it would also reverse the list.  Maybe not space efficient but simple to code and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. you are not saving the new `head` once it is returned (when you reach the end of the list), so the returned `head` is always going to be the one of the first stack of recursion, which is the original first node;
2. you are not assigning `node.next` to `null` on  the first node, so it will never become the new tail of the list.

This is the corrected code:

```
public Node reverse(Node head) {
    Node node = head;
    if (node.next == null) {
        head = node;
        return head;
    }
    Node next = node.next;

    // fix for problem 2, we transform the current node in the tail
    node.next = null;

    // fix for problem 1, head is now the tail node
    head = reverse(next);   

    next.next = node;

    return head;
}
```